# Blender. Настройка компиляции pythona в bge

Tags: python, blender

Набираю скрипты, а затем сразу их подключаю все работает, но если попробовать протестить на ошибки, запустить скрипты в текстовом редакторе то вылезет ошибка.

`ImportError: No module named 'bge'`

Возможно ли это как нибудь настроить?

Comment: ваш вопрос как скрипты для встроенного в blender Питон-интерпретатора (в том же процессе выполняется), запустить снаружи и без blender?

Comment: Запуск в блендере. В самом блендере, например  ругается на 'import bge', режим Blender Game

Comment: связанный вопрос ["ImportError" No module named 'bge' in OSX](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/92561/49296) Вам нужен вариант,  с Python controller (не "run python").

Comment: возможно ли проверить код в текстовом редакторе? или bge может использоваться только при запуске сцены?

Comment: Что происходит, если нажать P в режиме Blender Game?

Comment: Сори за тупость, вроде разобрался. Неправильно поставил вопрос, хотел узнать где именно посмотреть отладку bge, про консоль совсем забыл.